# Google Chrome displays mobile version only of my website in Ubuntu 15.10 . I only want desktop version

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, ubuntu-15.04

I have a Wordpress website. It displays on my laptop (Toshiba Satelltie A45) as a mobile site only in Ubuntu 15.10 on Google Chrome and FF.

However, Kubuntu 14.10 shows it on the same laptop correctly as a desptop version on Google Chrome.

I have not found a working solution that forces Chrome to show the site in the correct desktop version.

Does anyone know the solution, please?

Tested all fixes suggested on the Net without success. It must have something to to with the screen size (13 inches).

Comment: Probably better asked on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could try zooming out by pressing ctrl + - (minus) or zooming out using the menu.

I've seen zooming in/out like that work as a way to trick sites into displaying a different responsive template.

Answer (score 0):

You could try request desktop version.  You can do this by clicking on the settings on the right hand side of the chrome browser and it should be there. You could also scroll down to the bottom of you word press website and look at the tiny text and the bottom, there should be an option for a desktop version.

Comment: Does this work for Chromium on Ubuntu 16.04?  I'm not seeing the option "request desktop version"